# Karate : UI - Jenkins Integration

Tags: docker, jenkins, integration, karate, ui-testing

I have a doubt regarding Jenkins integration with Karate. We are using karate for ui testing. And we need to integrate it with Jenkins and should be running inside a docker container. The issue we are facing is - chrome is not getting invoked.Chrome is not starting only when we try to invoke test using mvn commands using entrypoint.sh. Can anyone help us on this ?